# Gmail forwarded email that can be readily replied to the original sender?

Tags: gmail

A sends an email to B who finds the email is meant for C. So B forwarded the A's email to C by Gmail forwarding.

C receives A's email from B, types something and clicks reply. Now B receives C's reply instead of A. Unless C explicitly changes the TO address of the reply which is very unintuitive and most of the time we just forgot it.

Is there any way for B to forward the email to C so C and A can immediately communicate with each other? How to forward an email so the reply goes directly to the original sender in Gmail?

Comment: this is a common email issue but with no workaround due to double edge sword danger to all participants

Answer (score -1):

Thus isn't a Gmail problem.

When you find yourself in this situation don't forward the email. Do a "reply all" and then add user C to the To/CC line. Putting a single line at the top "replying at add user C to the email".

Now of course you will still receive all subsequent messages unless somebody makes sure to drop you from one of the future replies.